# How to remove files from versioning in Git without deleting them, both locally AND ON A REMOTE repository

Tags: git

I have a versioned directory that contains a bunch of pdf resources that aren't really appropriate for versioning, but still need to be there alongside some html files that I actually do want versioned. The same folder exists on both a test server and a production server, and I use git to deploy changes from one server into the other. I want to remove the pdfs from versioning without deleting them from the working directory on either server.

I've used `git rm -r --cached`, which removes them from the git repo without deleting them from my working directory, and I've added them to `.gitignore` so Git won't see them as untracked files, but when I commit the changes and pull the changes into my other server all those pdfs get deleted from the working directory on the other server. I want them to stay. Any advice?

Note that this is **not** a duplicate of questions involving deleting from the cache without deleting from the **local** file system. It is about a distributed scenario.

Comment: Did you commit the .gitignore change as a seperate commit, or is in the same commit at the removal of the pdfs?

Comment: I added the .gitignore in the same commit as removal of the pdfs from cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following on the server:

- `git pull` to get the changes, pdfs will disappear temporarily.
- `git reset HEAD~1 --hard`  This should move you back to the commit before the pdfs were removed.  HEAD~1 is shorthand for the commit before the current commit.  If the files were removed a few commits ago, you can replace HEAD~1 with the SHA of the commit before you removed the pdfs.
- `git reset ORIG_HEAD --mixed` This will point your branch back at the correct commit and reset the staging area, but not reset the files in your working directory.
- If the .gitignore was modified in the same commit as the pdfs were removed, you will need to `git checkout -- .gitignore` to get it back.

After these steps the pdfs should still be there and your repo should be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps..

1. Add all pdf files
2. Push the code
3. Update .gitignore
4. Make a commit a push again

So that, the files on git server won't get deleted. But since they are in .gitignore, they won't be versioned. Means when you make a pull, you will have the pdfs too.

For example, look at [this repo](https://bitbucket.org/manupsunny/asd). It has two files, `asd.txt` and `qwe.txt`, where `asd.txt` is ignored using .gitignore. But still, when you pull the code, you will get both the files.

Comment: The `.pdf` files that have already been added will still be tracked; `.gitignore` will just prevent *new* `.pdf` files from being added.